# Which symbol gets DownValues or OwnValues when using SetDelayed?

Tags: core-language, reference-request, language-design, downvalues

I have been looking at various usages of `Pattern` objects. Here's a number of ways to define the same thing:

```
mod[x_] := {x}
```

which gives `mod` `DownValues`. Nothing unexpected.

```
e : mod[_] := ReleaseHold @ (Hold[e] /. mod -> List)
```

This is nice, as we don't need to give the argument of `mod` a name now.

```
e_mod := ReleaseHold @ (Hold[e] /. mod -> List)
```

Now we don't need to specify the pattern of arguments to `mod` at all. However, all three lines of code give `DownValues` to the symbol `mod`.

Let's look at the `FullForm`:

```
SetDelayed[mod[Pattern[x, Blank[]]], List[x]]
SetDelayed[Pattern[e, mod[Blank[]]], ReleaseHold[ReplaceAll[Hold[e], Rule[mod, List]]]]
SetDelayed[Pattern[e, Blank[mod]], ReleaseHold[ReplaceAll[Hold[e], Rule[mod, List]]]]
```

The first example is nothing special, the first argument of `SetDelayed` has the `mod` head, thus `mod` gets the `DownValues`. However the next two examples have head `Pattern`. If we use `someOtherHead` instead of `Pattern`, (in the second definition) we will get a "function" that does this:

```
someOtherHead[e, mod[x]]
(* e *)
someOtherHead[e, mod[x, y]]
(*     someOtherHead[e, mod[x, y]] *)
```

and if we add the third definition as well, then:

```
someOtherHead[e, mod[x, y]]
(* e *)
```

So clearly there are some special rules for the head `Pattern`.

My question is three-fold:

- How does MMA choose, which `Symbol` gets its `DownValues` in a `Set` or a `SetDelayed`? Especially I am interested in the non-standard procedure, as in my last two examples, but will be happy to get better insight in the standard case presented in my first example.
- Where is this behavior documented, if at all? I am primarily looking for references, but will happily accept answers from those who know how this works even if they cannot point me to a specific reference.
- A sub-question of the previous two: where can I find the special rules specifically for the head `Pattern`?

Answer (score 2):

Your constructions were very instructive.  Are you, to put your first question differently, asking why it is *mod* gets the downvalues in all three case; especially when examples 2 and 3 clearly show that *Pattern* is the head?

This may not help but the documentation of the symbol ":" says that *s*_*h* is equivalent to *s*: _*h*--the name *s* is given to the pattern with head _*h*.  Also the definition of _ (Blank) says that *_h* is any expression with head *h*.  Presumably this means as well that *s*_*h* is also an expression *s* with head *h*. In that case we have something like *f*[*x*_]=*x*^2 in which the head, *f*, gets the rule (*x*^2) as a DownValue.  Therefore your 2nd and 3rd definitions apply to any expression with head mod, so mod gets the downvalues.

Again, this may not be informative but I decided to try to address your question because I've been trying to understand ownvalues, downvalues and upvalues for some time.

Comment: That's an interesting take. Are you trying to say, that regardless of the `FullForm`, the expression `e_mod` is treated as an expression with `Head` `mod`, rather than `Pattern`? (+1 anyway)