# Extracting expressions from LHS of an assignment

Tags: expression-manipulation, assignment

I need to list all variables in a notebook containing several `Set` assignments, `lhs=rhs`, and equations, `lhs==rhs`. Part[] works as expected in the case of an equation,

```
eq1 = f1 == Sin[x]
```

where, `eq1[[1]]` returns `f1`. If you examine the Treeform for eq1 its easy to work out the Part specification for each element.

[image]

However, I can't get the form using `Set` to work. I presume this is because the *lhs* is replaced by the *rhs* on evaluation. To prevent evaluation I use `HoldForm[]`, this gets me one step closer, and in fact the `TreeForm[]` for the expression is what you would expect,

```
eq2= HoldForm[ f2[t_]=a t + b ]

TreeForm[eq2]
```

[image]

The snag is `eq2[[1]]` does not return what I would expect. What is the part specification for `f2` in this case?

Comment: Try: `eq2[[1, 1, 0]]` or `eq2[[1, 1]]` for the LHS. `0` is for the head of the expression. If you want everything underneath, use the second variation.

Comment: eq2[[1, 1]] returns b + a t_

Comment: Quit Kernel and start fresh.

Comment: If you have more complicated expressions and want to extract ``Set`` also from a deeper (unknown) level, you can try with ``Cases``, i.e. ``Cases[eq2, HoldPattern[lhs_ = rhs_] :> lhs[[0]]]``.

Comment: I tried the quit kernel and it still returned b + a t_

Comment: To extract parts unevaluated, for example by wrapping `HoldForm` around them, you can use e.g. `Extract[eq2, {1, 1, 0}, HoldForm]` or `Extract[eq2, {1, 1}, HoldForm]`

Comment: I am on v12.2.0 and this is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUj5y.png) I see.

Comment: Sorry - I had this a few lines above  'f2[t_] = a t + b'  !  @thorimur I've just discovered Extract and Position which are useful.

Comment: `eq2 = Inactivate[f2[t_] = a t + b, Set | SetDelayed]`
with
`TreeForm[eq2]` or `eq2[[1,0]]` might give the result you want, but I wonder: Do you want to rewrite your notebook or process it to extract the variables that are `Set` in it? Do you have to consider more complicated patterns on the LHS, such as `f2[t_] /; t > 0 = a t + b`?

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/92376/which-symbol-gets-downvalues-or-ownvalues-when-using-setdelayed (but no satisfactory answer for the problem at hand)

Comment: @Michael E2 thanks for spotting the key point! My ultimate goal is to create a list of the left and right hand sides for all `Set`, `SetDelayed`, and `Equal`, equations in a notebook. I've tried using `Inactivate` and you're intuition is right, it also does what I need. I'll try and create an example to illustrate what I'm doing (will have to wait a couple of weeks tho).